# Interview Probability Brain Teaser

Tags: statistics, probability

This is a question from the test our department gives to recent graduates. We're divided on the correct answer.

A mathematics class is composed of 10 students: 6 boys and 4 girls. 50% of the students are handed Test A to solve and the rest are given Test B. What is the probability that a girl gets Test A?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Should the answer be 0.5 ? Its pretty simple..

Answer (score 0):

Since we answer programming questions here, here's an answer how to compute the probability.
I take that you mean: *What is the probability that* at least one *girl gets Test A?*
This can be computed by dividing the number of assignments of tests to persons where *a girl gets Test A* by the total possible number of permutations. To generate those assignments, it suffices to permute either the class or the tests; e. g. in R:

```
> library(combinat)
> class = c(rep('b', 6), rep('g', 4))
> sum(unlist(permn(class, function(pt) 'g' %in% pt[1:5])))/factorial(10)
[1] 0.9761905
> tests = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5))
> sum(unlist(permn(tests, function(pt) 'A' %in% pt[7:10])))/factorial(10)
[1] 0.9761905
```

We see that permuting the class or the tests yields the same result.